# Where is a proper place to add a .h file in an iOS project for common macros and debug function?

Tags: ios

Say, if I have one or two debug functions or macros, where is a good place to put them in an iOS project so that the function can be used by all other files?  Would it be a `.h` file some where, and all the files that use it will need an `#import "filename.h"`?  Is there a common practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them available to the entire project and it doesn't take up too much space, I usually just insert it into the project's `.pch` file.  If it's long, I put it in a `.h` file and `#import` the file in the `.pch` file.

Comment: is `.pch` some precompiled header...  if so, won't it get wiped out if anything is placed in it by us?

Comment: No, it doesn't get wiped out.  It is automatically generated for you when you create a project, but is not modified again by the system.